# freemind shortcut keys are not working in linux

Tags: freemind

Hi
 most shortcut keys such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>,... not working in freemind when I run it in Linux. 
 
I don't have any problem with these shortcuts in other applications.
please help me.

```
<code>
FreeMind version is 0.9.0
information about linux:
Linux kali 3.12-kali1-486 #1 Debian 3.12.6-2kali1 (2014-01-06) i686 GNU/Linux 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
</code>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i delete all my custom configuration through by follow command.

`rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dmrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/user ~.compiz*`

  it work for me and hope it work for anybody whom face this problem.
  good luck